# Best libraries for Android developer (graphic)

Tags: android

I'm looking to good looking libraries / plugins (just stuff) for android.
I mean something cool like material intro etc. Something what makes app more atractive. Please help me guys!

Answer (score 1):

pretty general question.  You'll probably get a better response if your question is more specific to a single problem.

here's a library which covers a lot of material widgets - https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

however a lot of this is now in the standard android design lib - http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html